# updating datatable column based on values of another column in group

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to add pass-fail criteria to a matrix of units based on its voltage values. for example, if any of the pixels are greater than 4.5 volts then the entire device should fail. device coordinates are given by Row and Col, and individual pixel coordinates are given by PixelRow and PixelCol.

Algorithm -> groupby row and col -> check if any voltage > 4.5 -> assign fail or pass to all pixels in device

my table

[image]

output table

[image]

I did do some sort of attempt, but it's not working, how can I do so in C# linq (dotnet 4.0)

```html
my_Table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => Row = r["Row"], Col = r["Col"])
                       .Select(g => {
                        bool vf_passfail = g.Any(p => (double)p["Voltage"] < 4.5)
                        if(vf_passfail)
                        {
                        g.ToList().ForEach(r => r.SetField("PassFail", "Pass"))
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        g.ToList().ForEach(r => r.SetField("PassFail", "Fail"))
                        }
                        
                        return g
                       })
```

Comment: _"for example, if any of the pixels are greater than 4.5 volts then the entire device should fail": You mean lower than?

Comment: no.. greater than, view the output table for clarity

Comment: @JohnG: Thats not the logic. All associated rows of the current row-col group must be lower than 4.5 to pass, not only this single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can group by row and col and use `Any`, but i would use `ToDictionary`:

```
Dictionary<(int Row, int Col), (List<DataRow> Rows, bool Fail)> rowColFailLookup = my_Table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => (Row: r.Field<int>("Row"), Col: r.Field<int>("Col")))
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => (g.ToList(), g.Any(r => r.Field<double>("Voltage") > 4.5)));

foreach (var kv in rowColFailLookup)
{
    kv.Value.Rows.ForEach(r => r.SetField("PassFail", kv.Value.Fail ? "Fail" : "Pass"));
}
```

Maybe the query is not so readable so i try to explain.
I'm grouping by the row-col-tuple and use that also as key for the dictionary. As value i store the associated DataRows(as `List<DataRow>`) and the bool-result which can be determined with `Any` on these rows.

Later i enumerate those groups and their `DataRow`s and set the result in `PassFail`.

Comment: how can I create my original datatable from it?

Comment: @Adhil: why you want to create the table from it? Your sample code(and also the title of this question) shows that you want to update the field `PassFail` on all rows with the correct result. That's what i'm doing. The table itself existed already.